# Templates django не отображаются русские буквы

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, можете помочь или пнуть в нужном направлении?
Есть html файл, в нем есть в тексте русские символы. Когда открываешь его на сайте, то выдает ошибку:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 84: invalid
>   continuation byte

Вот так он выглядит через Subline Text:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>post005</title>
</head>
<body>
ëâüïëüï
</body>
</html>
```

При этом, если открыть через notepad++ этот же файл, то там вместо непонятных символов нормальные русские буквы

Comment: Открывайте в кодировке UTF-8 и сохраняйте в кодировке UTF-8. Где открывать — неважно, главное чтобы всегда была только кодировка UTF-8. Nodepad++ и Sublime Text кодировку UTF-8 поддерживают. С ней всё будет хорошо.

Comment: А если у меня файл создается функцией, как его сделать в кодировке utf-8?

Comment: Научите вашу функцию использовать UTF-8, как — зависит, очевидно, от самой функции

Comment: Хорошо, Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Везде где нужна кодировка UTF-8 добавляйте в первую строку файла следующее:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Если данные берутся из БД надо поменять кодировку БД